# Python:Query set has no attribute 'start_time'

Tags: python, django

My Meeting model  is Here

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    meetingID = models.CharField(max_length = 50) 
    venue = models.ForeignKey('MeetingRoom',related_name ='meetingroom',null = True,blank = True)   # whether One Time or Recurring
    status =models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    recurring_time = models.CharField(max_length=50)              # (Recurring date schedule information)
    attendee_passwd = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    moderator_passwd = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)               # it should be auto fill 

    meeting_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now,blank=True, null=True)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    reminder = models.BooleanField()
    start_time = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    end_time = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    meeting_duration = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    duration = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('User',related_name ='meetingroom_created')
    sms_no = models.IntegerField()  #participant will call on this number   Unique for all users and participant 
    conferenceID = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    meeting_logout_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    max_participants = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    participants = models.ForeignKey('Participant',related_name = 'parts_of_meetingroom',null = True)

    def disable_from_meeting(self):
        try:
            get_participant = Participant.objects.filter(meeting_id =self.id)
            for get_pp in get_participant:
                get_pp.status = 0
                get_pp.save()
        except:
            LOG_INFO('Organization %s has no PARTICIPANT IN %Ssuser ', self.id)
            pass  
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'testsite'
```

now in my views when i am trying to store the start_time in dictionary like

```
            get_all_user_of_org = User.objects.filter(org_name =get_org)

            for user_id in get_all_user_of_org:
                mee_data = {} 
                get_meetings = Meeting.objects.filter(created_by = user_id.id)
                print dir(get_meetings)
                mee_data['start_time'] = get_meetings.start_time 
              #  mee_data['end_time'] = get_meetings
                getall.append(mee_data)
```

then why i am getting the

```
 AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'start_time'
```

Here no reason to show this error because start_time is the attribute of my Meeting table

please help me what might I do wrong ?

Comment: What's the result of dir(get_meetings) - does it show start_time?

Comment: do you want the start_time off all meetings of the user?

Comment: ['__and__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__module__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__or__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_as_sql', '_clone', '_db', '_fill_cache', '_filter_or_exclude', '_for_write', '_iter   ............ value truncated

Comment: just curious - why do you have start_time and end_time as CharField as againsta datetimefield @user1667633 ?

Comment: @karthikr: there's more wrong with his model than just that... Why are there two 'duration' fields and why are the durations charfields? why is there a duration field if you have the start_time and the end_time? why is there a different field for start_time and meeting_datetime? why is the logout url in the model? why are two passwords stored here and both in plaintext? etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Meeting.objects.filter` is not returning a `Meeting` - it is returning a `QuerySet` of meetings. You can iterate through the `QuerySet` to get the meeting time of each meeting:

```
for user_id in get_all_user_of_org:
    mee_data = {} 
    get_meetings = Meeting.objects.filter(created_by = user_id.id)
    print dir(get_meetings)
    for meeting in get_meetings:
        do_something_with(meeting.start_time)
```

You have to realize you're dealing with more than one meeting here, and they might have different start times. You'll know best what you want to do in that case. Probably something like this?

```
for user_id in get_all_user_of_org:
    get_meetings = Meeting.objects.filter(created_by = user_id.id)
    for meeting in get_meetings:
        mee_data = {} 
        mee_data['start_time'] = meeting.start_time
        getall.append(mee_data)
```

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhh damn true i did a mistake here thanks for kepping me back on track

Answer (score 0):

Well you are using

```
get_meetings = Meeting.objects.filter(created_by = user_id.id)
```

This return type of `filter` is a queryset object which can have one or multiple objects.
To get the `start_time` of all the `meetings` of a `user`, you should use something like

```
get_meeting_start_times = Meeting.objects.filter(created_by = user_id.id).values_list('start_time', flat=True)
```